# bash script for executing commands on multiple server

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want a script which will restart the defined services on their respective servers. I want to pass parameter as below to the script:
eg:

```
sh execute.sh 
Enter your server and service list: [server1:nginx,mysql],[server2:mysql,apache],[server3:mongodb,apache]
```

By this input the script should verify and start the services on the respective servers. I am able to do this on a single server by declaring variables.

```
#!/bin/bash

Instance_Name=server1
Service_Name=(nginx php-fpm mysql)
SSH_USER=admin
SSH_IDENT_FILE=~/credentials/user.pem

len=${#Service_Name[*]} 
i=0
while [ $i -lt $len ]; do 
service=${Service_Name[$i]}
ssh -i $SSH_IDENT_FILE -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SSH_USER@$Instance_Name 'service $service restart'
done
```

Now I don't have an idea to move forward. Please let me know if my question is unclear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about wrapping it in a big `for` looping through the name of servers?

Comment: @fedorqui can you give an example?

Comment: For example: `while read $server; do ... (execute your script with $server parameter) .... done < list_of_servers`

Comment: The array declaration is wrong.  You don't have to put comma unless you want those to be part of the elements in the array.  Say `Service_Name=(nginx php-fpm mysql)` instead.

Comment: But as I told you before I want user input like this format: [server1:nginx,mysql],[server2:mysql,apache],[server3:mongodb,apache]

Comment: @devnull yes you are right. typo by me :(

Comment: @tapasmishra  Use a regex to extract the server name from the user input

Comment: @VusP Please give me examples how to user regex to extract the server name from the user input? Also I need to extract the service name for the respective servers.

Comment: anybody with new idea?

Comment: Here's an idea: use Puppet (or Chef, or one of their other competitors).  Those are purpose-built for "running commands on multiple servers".

Comment: Make yourself a favour and learn some scripting language (perl, python, ruby, etc.). The shell is ok for very simple things, but as your problems get more complicated it becomes very unproductive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse your input parameters

```
# create an array of server:services
a=($(echo "$1" | gawk 'BEGIN { FS="[]],[[]" } ; { print $1, $2, $3 }' | tr -d '[]'))
# add a for loop here to iterate values in array with code below
for var in "${a[@]}" ; do
  # get server name
  server1=$(echo $var | cut -d ':' -f1)
  # get your services as space separated
  servs1="$(echo $var | cut -d ':' -f2 | tr ',' ' ')"
  # loop your services
  for s in $servs1; do
    ssh $server1 "service $s restart"
  done
done
```

If you like bash programming or have to learn it this is the 'bible' to me
Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide
An in-depth exploration of the art of shell scripting
Mendel Cooper
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Comment: thanks for the great help but still I am confuse how to add a loop for the first array. I am not a program though. Can you please help me by solving the puzzle.

Comment: Hi Luis, thanks for the quick response. Sure I will continue my reading on bash programming. But the above script you wrote is working for only first section of the user input `[server1:nginx,mysql],[server2:mysql,apache],[server3:mongodb,apache]` i.e. for server1 how to do with others? means server2 and 3

Comment: Fixed. Sorry :p forgot to other changes after adding the for loop.

Comment: Thanks Luis for your help my problem got solved. I have edited your script and now it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
#!/bin/bash
SSH_IDENT_FILE=~/credentials/user.pem
SSH_USER=admin

# tells 'for' to read "per line"
IFS='
'

for line in $(
# read input from 1st command-line arg (not stdin)
echo "$1"|\
# remove all services except (nginx php-fpm mysql)
sed 's/\([:,]\)\(\(nginx\|php-fpm\|mysql\)\|[^]:,[]\+\)/\1\3/g'|\
# make it multi-line:
#    server1 svc1 svc2
#    server2 svc1
sed 's/\[[^]:]*:,*\]//g;s/\],*$//;s/\],*/\n/g;s/[:,]\+/ /g;s/\[//g'|\
# make it single-param:
#    server1 svc1
#    server1 svc2
#    server2 svc1
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $1" "$i}'
);do
        IFS=' ' read Instance_Name service <<< $line
        echo ssh -i $SSH_IDENT_FILE -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SSH_USER@$Instance_Name "service $service restart"
done
```